# JS loop and maintain index of parameters that meet condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a bunch of `div`'s that I'm selecting by `getElementsByClassName` let's call it:

`let myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('small-divs');`

I need to set `innerText` conditionally to `myDivs` depending on whether each `<div>` in `myDivs` is `style.visibility != 'hidden'`

So I'm looping using a `for` loop and within the loop I have the condition checking for visibility:

```
for(let i=0; i < myDivs.length; i++){
  if(myDiv[i].style.visibility != 'hidden'){
    myDiv[i].innerText = letter + i; // letter is a user defined array of letters to use for 'rows'
  }
}
```

This is working as it should but my problem is that I need the `i` in `letter + i` to begin from 1 rather than from the element's index that meets the condition. Here's a pictorial of what I have:

This is before hiding any divs:

[image]

And here's what I have after hiding some divs and running the above code. Notice that the inner text starts from the index that meets the conditions. For instance I need "row K" to start from K1
[image]

How can I achieve this? Seems like a small step I should do that I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? Use a counter which increments only when a non-hidden div is found

```
let number = 1;
for(let i=0; i < myDivs.length; i++){
  if(myDiv[i].style.visibility != 'hidden'){
    myDiv[i].innerText = letter + number; // letter is a user defined array of letters to use for 'rows'
    number += 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I definitely knew I was missing something small.